# Storing multiple data frames into one data structure - R

Tags: r, dataframe

Is it possible to have multiple data frames to be stored into one data structure and process it later by each data frame? i.e. example

```
df1 <- data.frame(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6))
df2 <- data.frame(c(11,22,33), c(44,55,66))
```

.. then I would like to have them added in a data structure, such that I can loop through that data structure retrieving each data frame one at a time and process it, something like

```
 for ( iterate through the data structure) # this gives df1, then df2
 {
    write data frame to a file
}
```

I cannot find any such data structure in R. Can anyone point me to any code that illustrates the same functionality?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just put the `data.frames` in a list. A plus is that a `list` works really well with `apply` style loops. For example, if you want to save the data.frame's, you can use `mapply`:

```
l = list(df1, df2)
mapply(write.table, x = l, file = c("df1.txt", "df2.txt"))
```

If you like `apply` style loops (and you will, trust me :)) please take a look at the epic `plyr` package. It might not be the fastest package (look `data.table` for fast), but it drips with syntactic sugar.

Comment: Beat me!  You can also "iterate" through your list of data.frames with `lapply`.

Comment: Might be worth adding a line or two of code, as @Justin's answer had, just for completeness.

Comment: I added an example of how to use `mapply` to save the data.frames using `write.table`.

Comment: I found the second sentence above a bit cryptic but with a little bit of testing, I found it means 'if you want to save the two data frames stored in the list named 'l' to text files on a hard drive use mapply ...

Answer (score 8):

Lists can be used to hold almost anything, including `data.frame`s:

```
## Versatility of lists
l <- list(file(), new.env(), data.frame(a=1:4))
```

For writing out multiple data objects stored in a list, `lapply()` is your friend:

```
ll <- list(df1=df1, df2=df2)
## Write out as *.csv files
lapply(names(ll), function(X) write.csv(ll[[X]], file=paste0(X, ".csv")))
## Save in *.Rdata files
lapply(names(ll), function(X) {
    assign(X, ll[[X]]) 
    save(list=X, file=paste0(X, ".Rdata"))
})
```

Comment: +1, and list can even hold radically different objects, such as a `data.frame` as a first element, a `list` as the second element, and the outcome of `lm` as a third object.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra -- Glad you didn't mind me adding this. I just know what a time-saver those file-writing constructs would have been to me when I was an R neophyte...

Answer (score 8):

What you are looking for is a `list`. 
You can use a function like `lapply` to treat each of your data frames in the same manner sperately. However, there might be cases where you need to pass your list of data frames to a function that handles the data frames in relation to each other. In this case `lapply` doesn't help you.

That's why it is important to note how you can access and iterate the data frames in your list. It's done like this:

```
mylist[[data frame]][row,column]
```

Note the double brackets around your data frame index.
So for your example it would be

```
df1 <- data.frame(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6))
df2 <- data.frame(c(11,22,33), c(44,55,66))
mylist<-list(df1,df2)
```

`mylist[[1]][1,2]` would return 4, whereas `mylist[1][1,2]` would return NULL. It took a while for me to find this, so I thought it might be helpful to post here.