# loop through all files in a directory, read and save them in an object R

Tags: r

I need to loop through all files in a directory, read and save them in an object with the same name.

I tried the following but none of them worked:

```
files <- list.files(path=".", pattern="*.txt", all.files=T, full.names=T)

lapply(files, function(x) {
t <- read.table(x, header=F)  
out_x <- function(t)            
})
```

or

```
path = "."
out.file<-""
file.names <- dir(path, pattern ="*.txt") 
for(i in 1:length(file.names)){
file <- read.table(file.names[i],header=TRUE)
out.file <- rbind(out.file, file)
}
```

Comment: What do you expect from `out_t <- function(t)`?  That is not valid syntax.  Also, have you searched?  This question has been asked like 20k times.  `lapply(files, read.table)` seems like what you want

Comment: Isn't this just `lapply(list.files(pattern = "*.txt"), read.table)` ?

Comment: @Richard Scriven I have searched, I found the ones which I already posted

Comment: urely this has been asked and answered many times. -1 for not showing any evidence of having done searching.

Comment: my problem is they did not save the file in an object with the same name

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tools)

files <- list.files(path=".", pattern="*.txt", all.files=T, full.names=T)
```

The following code section comes from [How can I ask a user and read those files(s) into separate dataframes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669859/how-can-i-ask-a-user-and-read-those-filess-into-separate-dataframes/27669926)

```
filelist <- lapply(files, read.table, header=F)
names(filelist) <- paste0(basename(file_path_sans_ext(files)))
list2env(filelist, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

The following code section comes from [Storing multiple data frames into one data structure - R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12268944/storing-multiple-data-frames-into-one-data-structure-r/12269141)

```
lapply(names(filelist), function(u) {
assign(u, filelist[[u]]) 
save(list=u, file=paste0(u, ".Rdata"))
})
```