# How to write an R function that reads in a directory of text files, changes them, and saves into the same directory

Tags: r, nlp, text-processing, stringr

Have tried looking for an answer elsewhere but no luck, so here goes:

I have a directory full of `.txt` files containing natural language (legislation). I want to read in the directory, carry out some string manipulations on each file using a new function, and save the file in the same directory with a new filename.

Example data (note the "Commencement Information" line at the end):

```
example <- "(7) A person who is not a UK national commits an offence under this section if 
            — (a) any part of the arranging or facilitating takes place in the United 
            Kingdom, or (b) the travel consists of arrival in or entry into, departure
            from, or travel within, the United Kingdom. Commencement Information I2 S. 2 
            in force at 31.7.2015 by S.I. 2015/1476, reg. 2(a) (with regs. 6-8)"
```

I sorted out reading in a directory (with help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27912952/10734443) answer), which works fine:

```
files <- list.files(path="../txt_copies/", pattern="*.txt", all.files=T, full.names = T) #filenames
filelist <- lapply(files, read.delim) #read in files from the filenames list
names(filelist) <- paste0(basename(file_path_sans_ext(files))) #name list elements by filenames
list2env(filelist, envir=.GlobalEnv) #move the list elements into the global env as objects
```

The issue is my function:

```
page_cleaner <- function(x) {

  txt <- x

  # clean text and print confirmation
  txt <- str_replace_all(txt, "(F)(\\d).+?(\\n)", "")
  txt <- gsub("Textual Amendments", "", txt)
  print("Text cleaned of Textual Amendments")
  txt <- str_replace_all(txt, "(Commencement Information).+?(\\d)\\)", "")
  txt <- str_replace_all(txt, "(Commencement Information).+?(\\w)\\)", "")
  print("Text cleaned of Commencement Information")

  x <- txt

}

lapply(names(filelist), page_cleaner)
```

**It should return:**

```
[1] "(7) A person who is not a UK national commits an offence under this section if
     — (a) any part of the arranging or facilitating takes place in the United Kingdom, 
     or (b) the travel consists of arrival in or entry into, departure from, or travel 
     within, the United Kingdom.
```

It seems to work fine on the example when I call the function on its own, e.g. `page_cleaner(example)` but not on the list of files.

I was fairly certain this would work and I can't figure out where I went wrong. Those string manipulations work fine outside of the function. In the example data, they should delete everything from "Commencement Information" to the end of the string.

I already have a method for saving objects to a directory when this is all done, no need for help with that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the **list** for lapply, not the name. So, Modify this line:

```
lapply(names(filelist), page_cleaner)
```

to

```
lapply(filelist, page_cleaner)
```

---

Aditional suggestions:

You can simple use `stringr::str_remove` or `stringr::str_remove_all` to remove string.

```
page_cleaner <- function(txt) {

  # clean text and print confirmation
  txt <- txt %>% 
    str_remove_all("(F)(\\d).+?(\\n)") %>%
    str_remove("Textual Amendments")
  print("Text cleaned of Textual Amendments")

  txt <-txt %>% 
    str_remove_all("(Commencement Information).+?(\\d)\\)")
  print("Text cleaned of Commencement Information")

  return(txt)

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was partially helpful! Turned out another issue is that the reading-in code saved each string into a separate dataframe cell, so the function needed to call `txt[[1]]` instead of just `txt`.